# Initial Tomcat 5.5 heap size

Tags: tomcat, tomcat5.5

Anyone knows what is the initialTomcat5.5 heap size?

Comment: This question is best answered by googling for "tomcat 5.5 heap size". The answer is, it varies. Use 'ps auxwww | grep java' on *nix to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean default "max heap size" ? It depends on the underlying JVM version (not on Tomcat version).

Upto JDK 1.5 it is 64 Mb for the process.

In Java 6, the default maximum heap size is determined by the amount of system memory present.